# objc[989] objc_exception_throw failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I was just adding some more CCSprites to a CCLayer and it just starts crashing giving me the error: objc[989] objc_exception_throw failed. Is there like a limit to the amount of CCSprites you can have on a screen or something? I added the CCSprites doing the following with the CCSprites already declared at interface:

```
    L1Circle1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"LaserCircle.png"];
    [L1Circle1 setPosition:ccp(180,180)];
    [self addChild:L1Circle1];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, silly me. I fixed it. I forgot to put "LaserCircle.png" in my resources. So forgetting to put pictures in your resources causes that.

EXTENSION:
I found getting errors like these most likely mean you don't have that resource or selector... You can find the specific problem just by scrolling up a bit in the Output Log and it will tell where the problem occurred.